# spring kafka exception on startup

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I followed this kafka example  :https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-consumer-producer-example.html 
but got exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration.kafkaProducerListener
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/kafka/security/jaas/KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.kafka.security.jaas.KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

I've google but can not resolve this issue , is anyone know this?

Comment: Seems like you have incompatible versions of spring-kafka and spring-boot - that class was added in spring-kafka 2.0.0.M2 (the current release candidate is 2.0.0.RC1).

Comment: `[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]` spring boot 2.0 M3 will pull in spring-kafks 2.0.0.M3 - what are you using for dependency management?

Comment: hi @Gary Russell ,for some reason I have to use the  spring-boot-starter-parent of version2.0.0.M3, my kafka version is 10.2.0

Comment: @Gary ,where can I get the Compatibility of spring-boot and spring-kafka?

Comment: Hi @Gary, If I want to use spring-kafka 1.2.x, which version of spring-boot should i use(the latest compatible version) ?

Comment: Spring boot's default dependencies can be found in the [POM here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.0.0.M3/spring-boot-dependencies). Select the branch/tag for the version to see the equivalent versions. You cannot use spring kafka 1.2.x with Boot 2.0; it requires spring-kafka 2.0.0.M3 or later; to you 1.2.x; you need to use boot 1.5.x (1.5.7 will pull in 1.1.6 by default but it can be overridden to 1.2.x).

Comment: that really helps ,thanks @Gary